# changing camera position causes color of some vertices to disappear

Tags: c++, transformation, directx-11, hlsl

**EDIT**: I haven't set depth-stencil view, can it be a problem?

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729721.aspx), but when I change camera position in `XMMatrixLookAtLH`, color of some vertices disappear. It feels like I'm running into undefined behavior.

Here is the creation of world, view and projection matrices packed in `ConstantBuffer`:

```
ConstantBuffer cb;
cb.world = DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity();
cb.view = XMMatrixLookAtLH({ 4.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f });
cb.projection = DirectX::XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(XM_PI / 2.0f, (float)windowWidth / (float)windowHeight, 0.1f, 110.0f);
```

The layout is exactly in the order as they are created and layed out in vertex shader, too. I do transpose them. I also tried to declare the structure with `alignas(16)`, but it had no effect.

Here is my creation of the buffer:

```
ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(cb);
bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
bd.MiscFlags = 0;
bd.StructureByteStride = 0;
bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;

ZeroMemory(&initialData, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
initialData.pSysMem = &cb;

hr = device->CreateBuffer(&bd, &initialData, &constBuffer);

deviceContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &constBuffer);
```

Compared to tutorial, I'm initializing it  upon creation. I've tried to initialize it after, but it didn't change anything.

Here is my vertex shader:

```
cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register(b0)
{
    matrix world;
    matrix view;
    matrix projection;
}

struct PixelInputType
{
    float4 pos:SV_POSITION;
    float4 color:COLOR;
};

PixelInputType main(float4 pos : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
    PixelInputType output = (PixelInputType)0;
    output.pos = mul(pos, world);
    output.pos = mul(output.pos, view);
    output.pos = mul(output.pos, projection);
    output.color = color;
    return output;
}
```

It is very different from that in tutorial, because I couldn't make their version compile. I tried to comment view transformation, and it worked as intended.

I've also tried to debug the frame using NSight, it showed that triangles are **present**, but the color is lost.

I have no idea what could be causing such behavior. I'm compiling on x64. I removed checks for readability, but they are present in every call which returns `HRESULT`. On fail, the checker always throws. The cube is centered at the origin, exactly as in tutorial.

**EDIT**: The viewport `MinDepth` and `MaxDepth` are set to **0.01** and 1 accordingly.

Here is the screenshot from position (4, 0, 0):

[image]

and from position (1, 1, 1):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by the near plane clipping. You need to study near/far planes.

You define the near plane on D3D initialization.

```
// Initialize the Direct3D object.
result = m_D3D->Initialize(screenWidth, screenHeight, VSYNC_ENABLED, hwnd, FULL_SCREEN, SCREEN_DEPTH, SCREEN_NEAR);
```

Edit: You can read more detailed information from the link below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206341(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Basicly, all you need to do is zoom out. You are too close to the object and some polygons are not drawn since they are out of camera scope. Changing near plane value, you can change from how far the clipping begins. I'll add an example link for more detailed information.

Comment: Yes, try changing MinDepth to something close to zero and see how it affects the result. Also you can try putting the camera to a little bit more distant.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you are having a problem like this one. Please check the accepted answer.

http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113803/does-direct3d-11-enable-z-clipping-discard-by-default

Comment: This wouldn't be a good solution performance-wise but it can be helpful for debugging. D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC has a DepthClipEnable flag. You can try setting it to false and disable depth clipping. See if it solves your problem. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476198(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: With disabled clipping, it draws everything. Thanks! But I have no idea why it is clipping even on far distance. BTW let's cleanup previous comments :)

Comment: I haven't set depth stencil view, can it be a problem?